# Check each li under ul for input.disabled and remove ul only when all li have input.disabled

Tags: jquery, html-lists, hide, html-input

This is the situation:

```
<h5>Title 1</h5>
<ul class="filter-group">
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>

<h5>Title 2</h5>
<ul class="filter-group">
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"></li>
</ul>

<h5>Title 3</h5>
<ul class="filter-group">
<li><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide h5 and ul only when all inputs in li have class="disabled". In my scenario only Title 3 and everything with it should disappear, however, I can't find a way to check all li and its inputs for whether they all have said class.

This is my jquery:

```
$("ul.filter-group:has(li:has(input.disabled))").prev().hide();
$("ul.filter-group:has(li:has(input.disabled))").hide();
```

and unfortunately it also removes title 2 since it has one input that's disabled. How do I only select the ul where each li has input.disabled?

Comment: You do not have anything called filter-group

Comment: My bad, the ul class is actually filter-group

Answer (score 0):

```
$(“ul.filter”).each(function() {
  var $ul=$(this), $dis=$ul.find("input:disabled"), $input=$ul.find("input");
  $ul.toggle($dis.length==0 || ($dis.length>0 && $dis.length<$input.length));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about 1-line solution like you are trying but this will help you achieve the expected

```
var uls = $('.filter');
$.each(uls, function() {
    if( $(this).find('input').length === $(this).find('input.disabled').length ) {
        $(this).hide(); $(this).prev().hide();
    }
});
```